# iOS which server side language to choose, and which server backend is prefered when dealing with socket connections

Tags: php, ios, node.js, google-app-engine, sockets

i am working on an iOS app, it will use some real time messaging, as i see it, i have 2 options here:

Socket connection to the server, so it can respond when there is a message, or constantly quering the database for updates.

The only requirement is that i am writing it in ObjC and not Appcelerator or phonegap.

Id like to know which backend provider you believe i should choose, and which language i should use for the backend.

I have done a fair amount of research my self, and i have tried a custom server solution running PHP, i have also tried Parse, which i really liked, but the price is horrible when scaling. I have also heard alot of great things about google App Engine, while i have not tried it, i have tried their mobile kickstarter, which seems bad, considering that their sample project has multiple errors that have been sitting on their git for months without getting fixed.

Anyway what i am asking is, should i write my own custom backend? Or should i use Google app engine / Parse or something else? Should i use Node.js, PHP or Python?

Id like to save as much time as possible, and i have alot of experience with symfony, the PHP framework, and i have minor experience with phyton. I have little to no experience with node.js,  dont mind learning it tho.

Thanks a bunch for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Parse is great place to [start](https://parse.com/products/push).  You can get a free account (with up to 1 mil api calls) and also send push notifications extremely easily (for your messaging).  There are also tons of analytics as well.

Comment: Indeed it is, its quite easy to use, but the if i go with the database model i would have to do quite alot of queries, and 1 mil api calls pr month is not alot. If their tier 2 option was  40-50$ i would go for it. But 200$ for 15m api calls is not that satisfying.

Comment: Yeah I understand where your coming from.  The jump to the second level is a big one, but if your planning on developing an enterprise level app you need a stable and secure backend.  So by letting Parse do all the work for you its worth the money.